# Cypress can't open popup windows in headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm new to Cypress and recently started implementing e2e tests for our system. A peculiarity of this system is that the authentication happens on a popup window.

I've already successfully created a simple test that loads the site, waits for the authentication to complete and then asserts that the page title is shown. This test runs without errors using the cypress client (`cypress open`), but when I run it in headless mode (`cypress run --headless`) the test fails.

When I see the video from the headless run, I don't see the popup window appear like it does when I run it with the GUI. Has anyone else had an issue like this where popup windows don't show on headless mode?

I also found this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696439) on the Chromium site related to issues displaying popup windows in headless mode, so it might be related to that, but the bug appears as closed.

I'm using Cypress 6.1.0 and Chrome 87

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you provide some example code that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by an issue with the integration of my website with another service that for some reason only occurred on headless mode. After fixing that, it works ok.